# Do I get notification of accepted/rejected edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, notifications

I suggested an edit to another user's response to make it more relevant to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119614/how-do-i-force-outlook-vba-to-use-a-specific-address-book/25123860#25123860) question, and for a while I could see the suggested edit with a message about it becoming visible once peer reviewed.

When I went back to see if it had been accepted, the changes aren't showing. I think this means that the edit was rejected, but I was expecting a notification and a reason?

Comment: The edit was rejected. No, it does not notify you of this. If you have a link to your suggested edit, you can see why it was rejected. If your edit is accepted, you'll have a notification in the form of gaining two rep.

Answer (score 7):

You are not notified of the outcome of a suggested edit review, no. If you haven't yet reached the reputation cap for suggested edits (you can only gain a maximum of 1000 points from accepted edits) you *do* get a notice for the +2 reputation you earned.

You can see what happened to the suggested edit in your profile; go to the activity tab, and filter on suggestions.

Looking at [your 4 suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317958/martin-ks?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) you can find your [most recent suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5478291) was indeed rejected as changing too much of the original post.

Comment: I would like to make it clear that one part of the post is an excellent answer, while the other part is not. How might I do that within the rules?

Comment: @MartinKS: use a comment, vote accordingly? If you want the answer author to know that the untested code doesn't work, then state that in a comment. Note that you rarely need a 'edit' header in a post; we can all see the revision history of a post if we want to follow changes.

Comment: I just wanted to add for finding the suggested edits: once you're on the activity tab, go to the "all actions" tab. The filter for suggestions is on the "all actions" tab.