# Add an inbox notification for rejected edits

Tags: feature-request, rejected-edits, notifications

I would love to see an inbox notification for suggested edits which are rejected, similar to "comment" notifications but with the title of "rejected edit" and the reason in the text. A couple weeks back, someone gave me good feedback on a rejected edit (basically not to fix one tiny piece of a post with overall bigger issues), but since I never check under `all actions > suggestions` I never saw it, and I persisted in my erroneous ways.

It seems like there is an asymmetry between getting the green +2 notification for the accepted edit and no red inbox light for the rejected edit.  Wouldn't balancing this out promote better edit quality?

Related: this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267920/do-i-get-notification-of-accepted-rejected-edits) asks whether there is notification; my question asks that notification be provided.

Comment: I don't know whether this is an SO meta or SE meta question.

Comment: This is kinda related:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298174/let-me-comment-on-reviews-and-notify-the-reviewers.  I had asked that the suggested editor be included so we could communicate with them as well.  If it does get implemented it should show up as a notification.

Comment: This would be helpful because about a dozen times or so I find an edit was rejected simply because a >2k rep user edited the comment while my suggestion was sitting in the queue. And I don't find out until I check my edits.

Comment: @Trobbins users > 2k rep cannot just edit a post when there is an edit pending review. They have to first review your edit, then reject and edit it themselves. This will happen if you did not catch all of the major issues with the post, otherwise the user will most likely chose to improve your edit, which will auto-approve it.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Well, they actually *can* if they had the page loaded before the suggestion was submitted, or if they had the editor open, or if they have a userscript to add the extra link, or if they hack the link into the address bar themselves, or .... It's a fairly common occurrence.

Comment: I didn't know about the hacked link, could have figured that out but it seems counter intuitive when you could just reject and edit. For the other reasons, that does not apply if there is already a pending edit when the 2k user views the question. But, I get your point

Comment: YES THIS ABSOLUTELY. Rejecting edits is all well and good but if the editor never finds out then they are going to keep doing crap edits...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To kind of go along with you, if the editor never remembers to go back and look at the reasons the why reviewers rejected it, isn't much of the value of having the reviewers put a reason lost?

Comment: @DeadChex: Yes, definitely. At the moment.

Comment: This should be on SE Meta, not just SO, as it would apply to all SE sites. It is an excellent idea, as it improves *both* usability and productivity. It is _such_ a pain to have to (click) to go to user profile, (click) to go to all actions, and then search to see if the edit was approved or rejected. Plus what @LightnessRacesinOrbit says about crap edits. This is a winner of a feature request.

Answer (score 79):

**Yes. This. Absolutely.**

What is the point in writing edit rejection reasons when the editor rarely (if ever) comes back to find out what it is about their edits that people don't like?

Indeed, such editors may not even *realise* that their edits are not going down too well. Could this be one of the reasons that there are so many bad editors who just *won't stop*?

Comment: This could also be made similar to how rejected flags work. When you next suggest an edit a message will appear saying "hey, your last edit was rejected, here are the reasons why..."

Comment: @gunr2171 - Currently, if you have a rejected edit, your subsequent edit has a banner stating just what you propose. Something along the lines of "Your last edit was rejected. Please review that edit before making further edits" (or something like that).  However, it doesn't explicitly state what the reason for rejection was in the banner.  However, I must admit, I haven't seen that banner for a couple of months now, e.g. on Mathematics, my last 2 edits were rejected but I see no warning banner. Has it been deprecated, or is it because my reputation has increased beyond a threshold value?

Comment: We need for a notification. Any time I make an edit, answer, etc. it is for the purpose of providing useful information for everyone, not for myself. If it is rejected, I need to know it happened in order to correct the information so I can repost it in a better way. Simply losing the info forever with no notification is ridiculous. No responsible contributor would be okay with simply losing their info they provided without having the immediate opportunity to fix their edit, i.e., notification. Such people could optionally turn off a notification I guess.