# Rejected tag wiki edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, tag-wiki

I recently suggested edits to some tag wikis, and I tried to edit again, and suddenly I got this message:
[image]

1. I didn't see any notifications about rejected tag wiki edits.
2. I didn't see any reasons for why my edits were rejected.
3. I don't know if this is temporary or permanent.
4. What about designed error notification (with more details), instead of a blank page?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/users/4442606/or-assayag?tab=activity&sort=suggestions. I am particularly puzzled by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27927319)

Comment: 1) You don't get any notification for any rejected suggested edits, 2) check your [edit suggestion history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4442606/or-assayag?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), 3) edit ban is temporary, but can be lifted or extended manually by mods, 4) good question, but only SE staffs can work on it, not the community...

Comment: @AndrewT. 1. Why? 3. Legit. 4. This question wouldn't have been created If I see a message "You were banned from edit tags for X days, here is why: X, Y Z".

Comment: 1) see [this related feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298822/1364007); 4) - sounds like a good idea (that I don't think has been suggested) - why not post a [feature-request] for it?

Comment: Regarding the comments in my answer about plagiarism, it might be worth your while to read [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/284827) and [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/284827) for what happens in general if/when plagiarism is detected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay. Looking at the last eight of [your
rejected suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4442606/or-assayag?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) (I see you've suggested many recently which some would either consider trivial or use plagiarised content):

- [[abc] tag wiki except](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27936582)

  You suggested edit changes "behaviour" to "behavior". I'd have rejected this as the former is the British English spelling; the latter the American English spelling ([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/behaviour)). I'd say there's no reason to suggest an edit from one to the other (just like I'd reject an edit from "colour" to "color" or vice versa).
- [[.d.ts] tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27936548)

  I'd have rejected this because you've attempted to correct "intellisense" to "intelliSense" - the correct capitalisation is "IntelliSense" ([ref](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense)). Your suggestion was wrong.
- [[lexilla] tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27931628)

  I'd have rejected this because it appears to be copy-pasta from, e.g. [here](https://fossies.org/linux/scintilla/lexilla/src/README). Also note the reasons selected by the reviewers.

  > Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name *itself* is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe **why** and **when** a tag should be used.
- [[lexilla] tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27931627)

  Again I'd also reject - for the same reason as one reviewer:

  > This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author.

  Possible source: https://fossies.org/windows/misc/scintilla446.zip/scintilla/lexilla/src/README
- [[cronicle] tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27931608)

  Looks copied from, e.g. https://github.com/jhuckaby/Cronicle
- [[browser-nativefs] tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27931586)

  Here you changed the capitalisation of "javascript" when referring to the Stack Overflow tag. Stack Overflow tags are all lowercase, e.g. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) so the correct capitalisation of JavaScript (the language) should not be used for [javascript] (the tag).
- [(Orphan wiki except)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27927320) and [orphan wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27927319)

  Again I'd have rejected these as they're clearly copied from [the Wikipedia page for gibberish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibberish)