# Rejected Edits are not prominent

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I did not notice that edits of mine had been rejected - I only noticed the first because someone had the courtesy of commenting on the question I'd edited, then after more time I saw a message explaining I *might* be banned from editing. So I investigated and found several rejected edits.

My question is: why wasn't I informed, with a reason at the time the edit was rejected?

If I had been then I may not have made similar mistakes and not got the point of a warning.

Comment: Related *[Do I get notification of accepted/rejected edits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267920/do-i-get-notification-of-accepted-rejected-edits)* and *[add inbox notification for rejected edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298822/add-inbox-notification-for-rejected-edits)*.

Comment: It was asked and rejected (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123439/168333). However, if you look at the question that caused that answer, you'll see that the current system, described in Glorfindels answer, was eventually made in response to that feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a couple of rejected edits is no big deal. After all, there are a lot of reviewers around which do a questionable job of reviewing.

At some point, when you have too much of them, you will get a message if you try to edit a post, something along the lines of:

> Some of your recent edits have been rejected. Please review them to find out why they have been rejected.

with a direct link to your suggested edits.

Comment: If the review is unreliable then why have it in the first place? I would like to be able to edit without review. I suggest heavily lowering the limit for that.

Comment: @wil93: IMO wannabe editors are *way* more annoying than the occasional roboreviewer.

Comment: @wil93 once you reach [2k reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), you can edit without reviewing. Also, what Rad Lexus says.

Comment: @Glorfindel I know that but I would prefer if the limit was 1k or even 500, or just "having 20 accepted edits"

Comment: @wil93 As someone who reviews suggested edits, I think that lowering the limit would be bad. 20 edits is far too few; I have seen robo-reviewers approve 20 bad edits in a row for some people. Just wait until you have 2k rep; it's worth it.